# Material ui Text Field and Formik form with custom compnents

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

Hey I am using the FORMIK form and I have a bunch of custom components, basically a text field and the select component. I now want to add a date and time picker and decided to use the Material ui date-time picker. Here is my code so far:

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
```

Defining the field in the form

```
<TextField
                        id="date"
                        label="Proposed Match Date"
                        type="date"
                        value={selectedDate}
                        onChange={handleDateChange}
                        InputLabelProps={{
                            shrink: true,
                        }}
                     />
```

and then I am trying to capture the values on Submit like so:-

```
onSubmit={async (values, {setSubmitting}) => {
                setSubmitting(false)
                console.log(values)
```

All the fields are passing the value except the date picker field. which is passing some weird data but not the value.

I am changing state onChange of the date picker component like so

```
const handleDateChange = (event) => {
        setSelectedDate(event.target.value);
```

This what I see when I console.log the values

```
cmonth: "August"
cyear: 2021
format: "bestof3"
location: "phase5"
opponent: "Gaurav Verma"
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

​

Is this the correct way to do this? Is this doable, if yes what is the pattern?

Comment: whats the  weird data thats getting passed in? could be a date that didn't get parsed

Comment: I updated the question with what I see in console.log.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is a date and time picker for material-ui and Formik then I suggest you use [Formik Material-UI Pickers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik-material-ui-pickers)
Here is a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/915qlr56rp)

The code would go something like this

```
     <Field
          component={DateTimePicker}
          name="dateTime"
          label="Date Time"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yout don't need to handle state of date TextField separately. FORMIK will handle it's state. so you should modify your TextField like:

```
<TextField
      id="date"
      label="Proposed Match Date"
      type="date"
      value={values.date}
      onChange={handleChange}
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}  
/>
```

And remove your handleDateChange function from your code i.e :

```
const handleDateChange = (event) => {
        setSelectedDate(event.target.value);
```

Comment: if you are using FORMIK form, there values should be defined

Comment: if you can, share your full source code to https://codesandbox.io/